# What is the probability that a OU process hits an upper barrier U before a lower barrier L?

Tags: options, stochastic-calculus, mean-reversion, barrier, stopping-time

What is the probability that the arithmetic OU process $dx_t= \theta(\mu-x_t)dt+\sigma dW_t$ hits barrier $U$ before hitting barrier $L$ when  $L<x_0<U$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\theta>0$ (take $\tilde{X}=\mu-X$ if it is not the case)

Let us denote $\text{erfi}(x)$ the imaginary error function
Let us denote $\tau_L$,resp.$\tau_U$ the hitting time of $L$resp.$U$ where $L<U$

1) Using Ito's lemma, prove that :
$$Y_t = \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2}}\left(X_t-\mu\right)\right) \text{ is a martingale}$$

2) Using optimal stopping theorem, prove that :
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_L\leq \tau_U) = \frac{\text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2}}\left(x_0-\mu\right)\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2}}\left(U-\mu\right)\right)}{\text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2}}\left(L-\mu\right)\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2}}\left(U-\mu\right)\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look. But is $\beta$ meant to be $\sigma$ ?

Comment: you're right, I correct it

Comment: Thanks. Very nice technique. If you can put more details, more people are able to appreciate it.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to respond to this question.

Having looked at your answer, a plot of the given $P( T_L ≤ T_U )$  over the range of possible $x_0$'s between $L$ and $U$, seems wrong (the convexity seems to be the wrong way). 

If I change the signs of $(x_0-μ), (U-μ)$ and $(L-μ)$ to $(x_0+μ), (U+μ)$ and $(L+μ)$ I can get a plausible plot. 

However, simulations consistently show much greater probability of touching U than this formula suggests, when $x_0$ is near $L$ and μ is set near or beyond U,.

I may be doing something wrong, but is it worth checking your answer?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(\tau_L\leq \tau_U)=1-\mathbb{P}(\tau_U <\tau_L) $ I.e the probability to hit L before U is equal to 1 minus the probability to hit U before L. I admit I answer not exactly to your question. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks MJ but that's not the issue. Have a look at the plot of either $P( T_L ≤ T_U )$ as you've given it or 1 minus that. The curvature is the wrong way for both. You can best see that when you set $\mu$ near either U or L. The curvature is the right way if I change the signs as stated, but that still leaves a large gap between the formula and simulation results.

Comment: I should add that the formula simulation gap is much bigger if I leave the signs in the formula untouched.

Comment: I look at $P (\tau_L \leq \tau_U) $ If you draw it wrt $x_0$ it has a nice decreasing shape going from $1$ when $x_0$ is close to $L $ to $0$ when $x_0$ is close to $U $. There is no special curvature. I might help you if you please tell me what you exactly expect and why.

Comment: There is always a curvature in your formula, but most obvious when you set $\mu$ at or beyond one of either L or U. The curvature should bring up the probabilities of hitting the barrier that is nearest to $\mu$. But in the formula as stated it does the opposite. That's what I mean by the curvature being the wrong way around. Have a look

Comment: my mistake, you are right, I see what you mean, i made a sign error, and I correct it above

Comment: ok thank you. I´ll have a look again. I will need to find an accurate and ideally fast erfi implementation that I can use from Excel. Any pointers on that? Thanks again

Comment: http://ddmf.msr-inria.inria.fr/1.9.1/ddmf?service=P0&rendering=PNG&mac=&sf_id=sf_erfi

Comment: @MJ73550 Well done, correcting the martingale from $Y_t = \Phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\theta}{\sigma^2}}\left(X_t-\mu\right)\right)$ to $Y_t = \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{\sigma^2}}\left(X_t-\mu\right)\right)$ fixes everything. Tying up nicely with simulations. Thanks again